# get the match of a string and unknown decimal numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have a very long data and I want to match and fetch a certain line that contains a string and unknown decimal value to that data.

The match that I want looks like this:

```
 "totalProfitToday": 0.0
```

where 0.0 is any decimal number. Any help? thanks.

Comment: Please show us a realistic (though no too large) sample input (or two).  Where is this data coming from?  Do you actually only need to capture the decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you're using or what you've tried but this regex assert that it starts at the beginning of the line, has your string, then zero or more digits, a period, and zero or more digits.

```
^"totalProfitToday": \d*\.\d*$
```

Change the * to + if you want 1 or more instead of 0 or more.

This live regex demo site can help you create, learn, and troubleshoot regex. https://regex101.com/r/au6rgb/1

Once you have the regex you want to match, you can use the function `preg_match_all()` to get an array of the matches.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
$data = '"totalProfitToday": 5.5';
$pattern =  '/^"totalProfitToday": \d*\.\d*$/';

preg_match_all( $pattern, $data, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

$matches will contain the matches. - You'll need to troubleshoot the results/pattern based on the data format.

Comment: I'm using PHP. Can you show me exactly how to do this? I'm new to this regex thing. I want to get the matched line.

Comment: Edited to include some sample code.  I'd try it out and post a new question with more specifics if you get stuck

Comment: Something important is missing.  Here is a hint: "Pattern Modifier"  Also, why call `preg_match_all()` if there is only one line to target?

Answer (score 0):

`\"\w+\:\"\s\d+\.?\d*` Matches all sequences of "word"+space+number with or without the decimal dot

`\"\w+\:\"` matches "word"

`\s` matches space

`\d+` series of numbers

`\.?` zero or one dot

`\d*` zero or more numbers

Comment: Ther\e is t\oo m\uch \escaping he\re.

Comment: @mickmackusa T\hen \cor\r\ec\t me :-)

Comment: I'll give you some time to research.